# A better way to handle NullReferenceExceptions in C#

Tags: c#, exception

I recently had a coding bug where under certain conditions a variable wasn't being initialized and I was getting a `NullReferenceException` . This took a while to debug as I had to find the bits of data that would generate this to recreate it the error as the exception doesn't give the variable name.

Obviously I could check every variable before use and throw an informative exception but is there a better (read less coding) way of doing this? Another thought I had was shipping with the `pdb` files so that the error information would contain the code line that caused the error. How do other people avoid / handle this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Always `Assert` liberally for null values.

Comment: @leppie - that's a lot of asserting! Yes I could do that but I was hoping for a more elegant solution to take into account situations like me forgetting to do that :)

Comment: Protip: Keep you methods small (say max 10-20 lines), then you dont really need line numbers.

Comment: @leppie: I disagree with the second part of that. Obviously keeping methods short is a good idea, but even so line numbers can significantly reduce the length of time debugging.

Comment: Check out ReSharper's [Visual Studio extension](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It's great for notifying you of such problems at design-time.

Comment: @Keith - thanks I'll have a look.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Your line numbers might be way off too, when running optimized. I am not sure if this is the case any more, but I recall getting bitten by this plenty times in .NET 1.1.

Comment: @leppie: I haven't seen line numbers being off - I've seen stack frames being *omitted* due to inlining, but not line numbers being present but wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly: don't do too much in a single statement. If you have huge numbers of dereferencing operations in one line, it's going to be *much* harder to find the culprit. The [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) helps with this too - if you've got something like `order.SalesClerk.Manager.Address.Street.Length` then you've got a lot of options to wade through when you get an exception. (I'm *not* dogmatic about the Law of Demeter, but everything in moderation...)

Secondly: prefer casting over using `as`, unless it's *valid* for the object to be a different type, which normally involves a null check immediately afterwards. So here:

```
// What if foo is actually a Control, but we expect it to be String?
string text = foo as string;
// Several lines later
int length = text.Length; // Bang!
```

Here we'd get a NullReferenceException and eventually trace it back to `text` being null - but then you wouldn't know whether that's because `foo` was null, or because it was an unexpected type. If it should *really, really* be a `string`, then cast instead:

```
string text = (string) foo;
```

Now you'll be able to tell the difference between the two scenarios.

Thirdly: as others have said, validate your data - typically arguments to public and potentially internal APIs. I do this in enough places in [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) that I've got a utility class to help me declutter the check. So for example (from [`Period`](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime/Period.cs)):

```
internal LocalInstant AddTo(LocalInstant localInstant,
                            CalendarSystem calendar, int scalar)
{
    Preconditions.CheckNotNull(calendar, "calendar");
    ...
}
```

You should *document* what can and can't be null, too.

Comment: yep, those are good tips. Should I be shipping with the pdb files so that the line is given? Currently my production code provides the method name but not the line which adds a degree of difficulty.

Comment: Along with 'don't do to much on each line' you can add 'don't do too much in each method'.  That helps to minimize the issue.

Comment: @directedbit: It depends on your situation... for server-side code, absolutely. If you're shipping client-side code, that *may* be more sensitive or messy...

Answer (score 3):

In a lot of cases it's near impossible to plan and account for every type of exception that might happen at any given point in the execution flow of your application. Defensive coding is effective only to a certain point. The trick is to have a solid diagnostics stack incorporated into your application that can give you meaningful information about unhandled errors and crashes. Having a good top-level (last ditch) handler at the app-domain level will help a lot with that.

Yes, shipping the PDBs (even with a release build) is a good way to obtain a complete stack trace that can pinpoint the exact location and causes of errors. But whatever diagnostics approach you pick, it needs to be baked into the design of the application to begin with (ideally). Retrofitting an existing app can be tedious and time/money-intensive.

Comment: thanks, is there any way you recommend to bake it in. Currently I have the simple approach of logging as much detail as possible for any unhandled exception.

Comment: The thing is, it depends on the particular method/location... sometimes you want specific information about what happened because you might be expecting certain types of errors. In others, like I said, you might have simply an unexpected situation. The first thing you can do is to hook `AppDomain.UnhandledException` (or `Application_Error` in global.asax for web apps), and then start retrofitting individual methods as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say that I will always make a check to verify that any object I am using in a particular method is not null.

It's as simple as

```
if( this.SubObject == null )
{
    throw new Exception("Could not perform METHOD - SubObject is null.");
}
else
{
...
}
```

Otherwise I can't think of any way to be thorough. Wouldn't make much sense to me not to make these checks anyway; I feel it's just good practice.

Comment: Not always. I usually extend exception. This is just an example.

Comment: In this case you should be using InvalidOperationException if the state itself is valid - and ArgumentNullException to stop you from getting into that state if it's not.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should *always* validate your inputs. If `null` is not allowed, throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

Now, I know how that can be painful, so you could look into assembly rewriting tools that do it for you. The idea is that you'd have a kind of attribute that would mark those arguments that can't be `null`:

```
public void Method([NotNull] string name) { ...
```

And the rewriter would fill in the blanks...

Or a simple extension method could make it easier

```
name.CheckNotNull();
```

Comment: that's good advice. Unfortunately this one was all me. I'd misplaced a bracket in the function so a variable was being used outside the scope of it's initialization.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking for a more compact way to code against having null references, don't overlook the null-coalescing operator `??` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Obviously, it depends what you are doing but it can be used to avoid extra if statements.